# How to change the symbol color of a mark line?

Tags: echarts

How can we change the color of a mark-line-symbol?
[image]

E.g. the line should be blue, but the end-symbol (the blue rectangle in the image above) should be red

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/v4czroqb/23/)

e-chart options:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'log'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
    markLine: {
      data: [
        [{
          name: 'start',
          coord: [0, 50],
          label: {
            formatter: name,
            position: 'end'
          },
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'blue'
          }
        }, {
          name: 'end',
          coord: [1, 500],
          symbol: 'rect',
        }]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't see a solution using `markLine` as the end point colour is based on the `lineStyle` have you considered using an additional `markPoint`?

[image]

The revised option would look like this, I've added a marked point and removed the start and end labels as they were not animating well

```js
let start = 50
let end = 500
var pi = Math.PI;
let angle = 90 - Math.tan( 1 / Math.log10(end - start)  ) * 180/pi

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'log'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
    markPoint: {
      data: [{
        symbol: 'rect',
        symbolSize: [20, 10],
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 500,
        symbolRotate: angle,
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'red'
        },
        label: {
          formatter: name,
          position: 'top'
        },
      }]
    },
    markLine: {
      data: [
        [{
          coord: [0, start],
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'blue'
          }
        }, {
          coord: [1, end],
          symbol: 'none',
        }]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

Revised [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grahamallan31/a5bvy9hx/4/)

Comment: actually I had tried that, but it's quite awkward - e.g. we must calculate the position rotation, etc.

Comment: Agreed, had you been using an average, min or max marker I would not have suggested it

Comment: I've filed a feature request: [#14257: Allow to set the color of markLine symbols](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/14257)